# Is it possible to share the same realm database file between two platforms?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, realm

If let's say on iOS app a realm database is created, can it then be sent as the realm file to macOS app and be used there?

Answer (score 0):

The offical solution for synching between devices is to use [Realm Platform](https://realm.io/products/realm-platform/) (expensive).  There is no explicit guarantee that the fileformat is going to be the same between platforms and especially between versions.  Of course you can also just serialize all of your tables to JSON and deserialize them on the other client and use something else like icloud or firebase to synch the data in between.

Answer (score 0):

A Realm file is compatible with all platforms (ObjC, Swift Java, JS and .Net). A file that was created on iOS can be read from macOS.

> Realms are cross-platform: as long as you don’t store platform-specific objects in a Realm, the data can be synced across operating systems. (In fact, the actual Realm data files can be copied between platforms.)

https://realm.io/docs/data-model/